# How to find the largest element locator in the case of a duplicate value

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find largest element locator.  This code works, but in case if I give largest element two times, then how can I return two locations?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestElementLocator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Read the input from the console
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows and columns of the array: ");
        //Read no.of rows
        int rows  = input.nextInt();
        //Read no.of columns
        int columns = input.nextInt();

        //Create new array object
        double[][] a = new double[rows][columns];
        //Input array of elements
        System.out.println("Enter the array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            a[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        //call the locateLargest and print
        int[] location = locateLargest(rows,columns,a);
        System.out.println("The location of the largest element is at (" + location[0] + ", " + location[1] + ")");
    }

    //method to determine the max val & postion

    public static int[] locateLargest(int rows,int columns,double[][] a) {
        int[] location = new int[2];

        double largest = a[0][0];
        //rows = 10;
        //columns = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                if (largest < a[i][j]) {
                    largest = a[i][j];
                    location[0] = i;
                    location[1] = j;
                }
            }
        }
        return location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of right now is:

1. Get the largest number first.
2. In the second iteration traverse through the array once again to find out the location of equal to largest elements.(Very less optimized approach though)
3. **Quick suggestion:** you can crate a `location` class with `getter/setter` for I, J. Along with this you can create a HashSet of all the locations which holds location objects.

Comment: No need for second iteration: if a larger element is found, just erase all elements in Arraylist/s which is/are storing locations of equal maxima.

Comment: I am just thinking about efficiency. Everytime we would be doing clean up.. think about a situation (3,3,3,5,5,6) total of 5 times we need to do clean up.

Comment: The code I've posted in my answer works and for the example you've given does 2 clean ups and only does one iteration. Don't you think that is efficient enough? It's far more efficient than doing 2 iterations, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array list to store all locations of largest. Something Like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LargestElementLocator {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Read the input from the console
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the number of rows and columns of the array: ");
//Read no.of rows
int rows  = input.nextInt();
//Read no.of columns
int columns = input.nextInt();

//Create new array object
double[][] a = new double[rows][columns];
//Input array of elements
System.out.println("Enter the array: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
a[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
}
//call the locateLargest and print
int[] location = locateLargest(rows,columns,a);
System.out.println("The location of the largest element is at (" + location[0] + ", " + location[1] + ")");
}

//method to determine the max val & postion

public static List<Location> locateLargest(int rows,int columns,double[][] a) {

double largest = a[0][0];
//rows = 10;
//columns = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    if (largest < a[i][j]) {
      largest = a[i][j];
    }
  }
}

List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    if (largest = a[i][j]) {
      locations.add(new Location(i,j));
    }
  }
}

return locations;
}
}

class Location {
  int x,y;
  Location(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the job. I'm not saying there's no better way of doing it, but I think it's the best way I've come up with so far.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestElementLocator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Read the input from the console
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows and columns of the array: ");
        //Read no.of rows
        int rows  = input.nextInt();
        //Read no.of columns
        int columns = input.nextInt();

        //Create new array object
        double[][] a = new double[rows][columns];
        //Input array of elements
        System.out.println("Enter the array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            a[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        //call locateLargest
        ArrayList[] location = locateLargest(rows,columns,a);
        // check how many largest elements there are and print
        if(location[0].size()==1)
        {
            System.out.println("The location of the largest element is at (" + location[0].get(0) + ", " + location[1].get(0) + ")");
        }
        else if(location[0].size()>1)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<location[0].size();i++)
            {
            System.out.println("The location of the largest element number "+i+": (" + location[0].get(i) + ", " + location[1].get(i) + ")");
            }
        }

    }

    //method to determine the max val & postion

    public static ArrayList[] locateLargest(int rows,int columns,double[][] a) {

        ArrayList[] location = new ArrayList[2];
        location[0] = new ArrayList(); // to hold row position/s of the largest element/s
        location[1] = new ArrayList(); // to hold column position/s of the largest element/s

        double largest = a[0][0];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {

                if (largest < a[i][j]) {
                    // a new maximum element has been discovered so get rid 
                    // of any previously stored maxima positions
                    location[0].clear();
                    location[1].clear();
                    largest = a[i][j];
                    // ArrayLists can't hold primitives, so wrap i and j in Integers
                    Integer I = new Integer(i);
                    Integer J = new Integer(j);
                    // store row and column positions of this maximum
                    location[0].add(I);
                    location[1].add(J);
                }

                else if (largest == a[i][j]) {
                    // a duplicate maximum has been found, so add 
                    // its row  and column positions to the list
                    largest = a[i][j];
                    Integer I = new Integer(i);
                    Integer J = new Integer(j);
                    location[0].add(I);
                    location[1].add(J);
                }

            }
        }

        return location;

    }
}
```

It does use an array of untyped ArrayLists which Eclipse warns needs to be paramterized, but it works fine. If you don't want any warnings in your code, you could replace the ArrayList array with a 2dArrayList: here's the 2dArrayList class I've used:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ArrayList2d<T> {

ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> array;

    public ArrayList2d() {

        array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();

    }

/**
     * ensures a minimum capacity of num rows. Note that this does not guarantee
     * that there are that many rows.
     * 
     * @param num
     */
    public void ensureCapacity(int num)
    {
        array.ensureCapacity(num);
    }

    /**
     * Ensures that the given row has at least the given capacity. Note that
     * this method will also ensure that getNumRows() >= row
     * 
     * @param row
     * @param num
     */
    public void ensureCapacity(int row, int num)
    {
        ensureCapacity(row);
        while (row < getNumRows())
        {
            array.add(new ArrayList<T>());
        }
        array.get(row).ensureCapacity(num);
    }

    /**
     * Adds an item at the end of the specified row. This will guarantee that at least row rows exist.
     */
    public void Add(T data, int row)
    {
        ensureCapacity(row);
        while(row >= getNumRows())
        {
            array.add(new ArrayList<T>());
        }
        array.get(row).add(data);
    }

    public T get(int row, int col)
    {
        return array.get(row).get(col);
    }

        public ArrayList getRow(int row)
        {
                return array.get(row);
        }

        public ArrayList getCol(int column)
        {
                ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
                for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
                {   
                    result.add(array.get(i).get(column));
                }
                return result;
        }

    public void set(int row, int col, T data)
    {
        array.get(row).set(col,data);
    }

    public void remove(int row, int col)
    {
        array.get(row).remove(col);
    }

    public boolean contains(T data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        {
            if (array.get(i).contains(data))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getNumRows()
    {
        return array.size();
    }

    public int getNumCols(int row)
    {
        return array.get(row).size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Efficient approach:-

By first storing the **First** element's location with its value(for checking the condition) in array then check for all other elements if the element is **same** with the element stored in a array then just store it in the next empty element and if element is **greater** than the element exist in array then just create new array and repeat above process upto the rows*column and rest don't touch the array.